# Is it feasible to transform each variable differently while doing multiple regression

Tags: regression, classification, random-variable

I have a dataset with 10 variables ...is it feasible to transform each variable differently while doing multiple regression...

for example
new_V1 = log(v1)

New_V2= V2^2

New_V3= 1/V3

Likewise differently for different variables and then applying multiple regression?

Comment: Feasible yes; sensible very often. Note that a simple case is having (together with others) binary predictors (indicator or dummy variables), in which case no transformation makes sense (and not transforming makes sense).

Comment: Feasible in what sense? Certainly it's possible.

Answer (score 8):

Yes. Sure. The key is to understand that in the expression "linear regression" the word "linear" means "linear with respect to the coefficients in front of variables". So, you can not only transform each variable differently, but, for example, make two different transformations of each variable and include both in regression. You should keep in mind, however, that ideally your variables should be uncorrelated with each other and roughly on the same scale.

If you are using R, you can transform variables directly in the formula without changing the data frame

```
lm(y ~ I(log(v1)) + I(v2^2) + I(1/v3), data=data)
```

In this case, if you want to make predictions for another data frame `newdata`, you can use it directly (without changing it).

Alternatively you can transform variables "by hand" in the data frame (introduce new columns with or without eliminating the old columns) and work with new variables

```
lm(y ~ new_v1 + new_v2 + new_v3, data=data)
```

To make predictions in this case, you need to transform variables in your `newdata` data frame (that is, introduce new columns) in the same way you transformed it in `data`.

The results of these two "implementations" will be the same. And both are linear regression.

Comment: So my reg equation will be  =Intercept+coef * antilog(new_v1)+coef *  (sqrt(new_v2))+coef * new_V3

Comment: No. Your regression equation will be `= intercept + coef_1*new_V1 + coef_2*new_V2 + coef_3*new_V3`

Comment: Y arent we considering the variable modification we did earlier.?

Comment: What do you mean with "did earlier"? You do _not_ transform your variables back. Consider creating new variables as creating new data frame with this (=new) variables only

Comment: Useful, but OP did not indicate use of R (if that is the software you are presuming) and many people interested in this will not be using R. A statistical answer is best phrased using statistical notation, not software instructions.

Comment: After your comment I realized, that R is indeed not indicated. Funny. In R if you read the data frame from a file without a header, the "automatic" names for variables are "V1", "V2" and so on. I looks like that I subconsciously assumed R.  Thanks for the comment anyway, I added some diescription

Comment: No. obv i wont transform it back...but the original dataset has different value ..suppose..V1 = ship tonnage in billions & we transformed it to new variable   NEW_v1= log(v1)  ..... Now while writing the equation you are saying i should write  eqn = intercept + coef_1*new_V1 + coef_2*new_V2 + coef_3*new_V3..........but to predict one would insert the variable value asit was originally like ship tonnage in billions....Dot u think we should adjust the reg equation as we have transformed the data

Comment: Yes. This is perfectly fine. What is the problem?

Comment: If you introduce new variables "by hand" by inserting new columns in your data frame, then you need to make the same transformation and introduce the the same new variables to the data frame you use for prediction. Thus, you work with "new_V" variables in each data frame and predict in terms of "new_V" variables. I extended my answer.

Comment: Thnaks..try to answer this  http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/151754/how-to-make-correlated-variables-uncorrelated       would be really helpful.